# Sort dictionary by value in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have a dictionary as `[String: [String]]`. Data looks like,

```
Province
  |- State 1
  |    |- A
  |    |- C
  |    |- E
  |- State 2
       |- B
       |- A
       |- D
```

I tried to sort this as,

```
let sortedResult = plistData.sorted{ $0.key < $1.key }.map { [$0.key: $0.value.sorted()] }
```

But this gives me an `[[String : [String]]]` type array. How may I fix this to get a [String : [String]].? Need to sort this by all values

Comment: You can't sort a dictionary in Swift.  By definition, the keys have no specific order.  You can maintain a separate array of sorted keys which may accomplish what you want.

Comment: I want to sort this by values. State 2's A,C,E array should be State 2 -> A, B, D

Comment: You can sort the values which are arrays, but you can't sort the keys because the dictionary will not maintain a specific order.  So in your example `State 1` and `State 2` may appear in any order.

Comment: yes. I want to sort the values inside the arrays

Comment: You need to specify this in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, you specified that you want to sort the value arrays.  You can accomplish this using `mapValues` and `sorted` like this:

```
let sortedResult = plistdata.mapValues { $0.sorted() }
```

Note: Dictionaries in Swift are unordered (have no specified order), so it isn't possible to put the keys into a specific order.  If you'd like to display the keys in a specific sorted order, then sort them into a separate array using `let sortedKeys = plistdata.keys.sorted()`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But when I'm using different locales, How may I sort this in an another language?

Comment: In that case, how are you getting the strings you wish to display?

Comment: Reading all from a plist(English only) file and localized it using the code

Comment: When you localize it, keep it in the same format `[String: [String]]` and then sort that.

Comment: I'm doing this `plistdata.mapValues { $0.sorted() }` after read the file. But it only works for English

Comment: You need to create a localized structure first, and then sort that.  Do you have a function which takes a string and returns a localized one?

Comment: I have such a function. `var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle.main, value: "", comment: "")
    }`

Comment: First create your localized structure like this and then sort it: `let localizedDict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: plistdata.map { (k, v) in (k.localized, v.map { x in x.localized })})`

Comment: Just a warning, if you have two states that localize into the same string, then `Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues)` will crash due to a duplicate key.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries can't be sorted, they don't maintain a position like array. You can sort the keys though, and from the sorted keys get the value from the dictionary:

```swift
let dictionary = [String: [String]]()
print(dictionary.keys.sorted())
for key in dictionary.keys.sorted() {
    print(dictionary[key]?.sorted())
}
```

Edit: I saw you mention in the comments about the requirement change. If you only want to sort the value here is how:

```swift
let dictionary = [String: [String]]()
let sortedDictionary = dictionary.mapValues { $0.sorted() }
```